# meaning of "somebody comes through"

Tags: meaning

> As you will see in the recipe section, Lindsay came through
> beautifully. The recipes are truly wonderful.

I'm guessing it means something like "did/finished the job". Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

She certainly did finish. But "come through" could mean two separate things about how the job was started.

In this context, ["come through" as a phrasal verb](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/come-through) could mean one or two things:

1. **to do something you've agreed to do**. e.g., "I asked Lindsay to create recipes and she came through beautifully."
2. **to overcome/succeed when faced with a challenge**: e.g., "I had asked Lindsay to create some recipes before her mother got sick. Lindsay was determined, however, and, as her mother healed, "she came through beautifully and produced these incredible recipes."

Comment: Seems to me that the first meaning you mentioned is the right one. Quite similar to the first meaning here: https://merriam-webster.com/dictionary/come+through
Thanks Ted!